# Unauthorized when using gocosmos to create a document

Tags: go, authentication, azure-cosmosdb

I got go-sql-driver for Azure CosmosDB from https://github.com/btnguyen2k/gocosmos.

It goes well when i call gocosmos.NewRestClient to get a rest client, CreateDatabase() to create database and CreateCollection() to create collection.

The problem is when i use CreateDocument(), i get response with statuscode 401 and body like this

```
{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'post\ndocs\ndbs/ToDoList/colls/Items\nmon, 31 may 2021 13:31:44 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: a9bbd729-3495-400f-9d79-ddec3737aa92, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0"}
```

i've tried all the solutions I've seen, but i haven't solved the problem.

Comment: Is this a SQL API account or MongoDB API account?

Comment: It's SQL API, i created this account by selecting "Core(SQL)".

Comment: @MarkBrown Is SQL API for go available？

Comment: There is no GO SDK for SQL API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmosdb-go-mongodb-quickstart) and with this sample code, I can successfully create database, collection and document. Here's my testing result, can it help you?

[image]

```
// connects to MongoDB
func connect() *mongo.Client {
    mongoDBConnectionString := os.Getenv(mongoDBConnectionStringEnvVarName)
    if mongoDBConnectionString == "" {
        log.Fatal("missing environment variable: ", mongoDBConnectionStringEnvVarName)
    }

    database = os.Getenv(mongoDBDatabaseEnvVarName)
    if database == "" {
        log.Fatal("missing environment variable: ", mongoDBDatabaseEnvVarName)
    }

    collection = os.Getenv(mongoDBCollectionEnvVarName)
    if collection == "" {
        log.Fatal("missing environment variable: ", mongoDBCollectionEnvVarName)
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
    defer cancel()

    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoDBConnectionString).SetDirect(true)
    c, err := mongo.NewClient(clientOptions)

    err = c.Connect(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to initialize connection %v", err)
    }
    err = c.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to connect %v", err)
    }
    return c
}

// creates a todo
func create(desc string) {
    c := connect()
    ctx := context.Background()
    defer c.Disconnect(ctx)

    todoCollection := c.Database(database).Collection(collection)
    r, err := todoCollection.InsertOne(ctx, Todo{Description: desc, Status: statusPending})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to add todo %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("added todo", r.InsertedID)
}
```

Comment: Emm, there is no auth error after i changed my cosmosdb account from using cosmos SQL API to using MongoDB API. Now my database wroks, but i'm confused why my SQL API didn't work?

Comment: @masha Mark Brown had a post here, he said sql api for golang is on backlog but not current road. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQcPQ.png   He also added a comment below your question, I think he will give you a nice reply.

Comment: If you feel my post maybe helpful to others, could you accept it as the answer? Thanks in advance : )